# How to make Cucumber not remove one record from DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Cucumber cleans TEST DB before every run.

But I have a couple values that should always be in the database. 
("default" ones).

Is there a way to tell Cucumber NOT to delete some values?
Or mb create before each run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it in a Given block in the Background section.

e.g.

```
Background:
  Given I have an item that exists

Given /^I have and item that exists$/ do
  Item.create!(item_name: 'Name')
end
```

Hope this helps.